# Power BI Unable to Grant Permission

Tags: powerbi

I want to share my dashboard with external users. For this, I am using [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content using a sample embed for your customers application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core). I am able to create a user in my `Azure AD` and now I am at `Set up your Power BI embedding environment`. Here I am unable to `Grant Permission` to my user.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have enough permissions to do that?
Did you try to do this in the Azure Portal?

Comment: @msta42a try to do what ?

Comment: to grant premission directly in Azure portal

Comment: @msta42a not yet I'll be checking it